# Get git commit hash of a tag without fetching the repo to local machine

Tags: git, github

I know how to get the commit hash of a git tag:
git fetch
git rev-list -n 1 "v1.0"

However, this requires us to pull/fetch the repository to local machine first.

I wonder if it's possible to get the git commit hash of a tag on a remote repository without checking out / fetching the tag to local working directory?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `git ls-remote` command. This command allows you to interact with a remote repository without modifying your local working directory.

below command will display the commit hash associated with the "v1.0.0" tag.

```
git ls-remote --tags <remote-repository-url> | grep "refs/tags/v1.0.0$"
```

**Note: I am just using this tag as an example**

Comment: It works great. However, the command returns the hash of the tag. Can we have it return the hash of the git commit pointed at by the tag?

Comment: so if you want the hash of the git commit try this  command `git rev-list -n 1 refs/tags/v1.0.0`

Comment: But this will require the repository to be pulled/fetched to local working directory first, as I mentioned in the question

Comment: I found the answer here: git ls-remote -q origin refs/tags/v1.0.0^{}

Comment: cool @HungNguyen